# Using multiple conditional statements for individual Controls and putting conditional statements in Public Methods

Tags: c#

I am trying to validate multiple fields/Controls based on individual conditions. The issue is I have individual labels that indicate an error based on the specific control rather than a message box; is there a more efficient way to do this?

**Here is the code:**

```
if (txtPhone. Text. Length <= 0) 
{ 
lblPhoneRequired.Visible = true; 
} 
else 
{ 
lblPhoneRequired.Visible = false; 
}

if (txtName. Text. Length <= 0) 
{ 
lblNameRequired. Visible = true; 
} 
else 
{ 
lblNameRequired. Visible = false; 
}
```

Finally I tried wrapping this into a Public method like this:

```
public void validation() {
if (txtPhone. Text. Length <= 0)
{ 
lblPhoneRequired.Visible = true; 
} 
else 
{ 
lblPhoneRequired.Visible = false; 
}

if (txtName. Text. Length <= 0) 
{ 
lblNameRequired. Visible = true; 
} 
else 
{ 
lblNameRequired. Visible = false; 
}
}
```

Then calling the method in a button click event but it does not work.

```
private void btnSample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
validation(); 
}
```

The is new territory so please bear with my ignorance:

Guy

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want to accomplish...

Comment: Is this ASP, winforms, WPF, silverlight, windows phone, or what?

Comment: Windows form: Using Visual Studio, I am asking two things. 1) Can this code be simplified, because I am validating individual controls, each with it's own error Label. 2) Can this work in a Method? - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten your code:

```
lblPhoneRequired.Visible = (txtPhone.Text.Length == 0); 
lblNameRequired.Visible =  (txtName.Text.Length  == 0);
```

Note that this is not more or less efficient than your appoach, but it is less verbose and maybe more readable.

Of course you could also use a single control with a different error message:

```
lblError.Visible =   (txtPhone.Text.Length == 0)
                  || (txtName.Text.Length  == 0);
if((txtPhone.Text.Length == 0) && (txtName.Text.Length  == 0))
     lblError.Text = "Enter phone number and name";
else if(txtPhone.Text.Length == 0)
     lblError.Text = "Enter phone number";
else if(txtName.Text.Length == 0)
     lblError.Text = "Enter name";
else
    lblError.Text = String.Empty;
```

But you should have a look at the [`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event  and the [`CausesValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) property which every control has.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that the error labels are set to Visible/False in the Control Property. If I use a Single Control, what happens if multiple fields were empty but need different error messages: Example: Name Required, or Phone required?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (txtPhone. Text. Length <= 0)
  lblPhoneRequired.Visible = lblNameRequired. Visible = true; 
else
  lblPhoneRequired.Visible = lblNameRequired. Visible = false;
```

Comment: But if the user entered no name `lblNameRequired` should be visible.